# Android Set Pager Tab using Button

Tags: java, android, pager

I have a pager in a Fragment and i need to set the tab from the main activity. 
While searching i found setCurrentItem is used, but it can be used only inside the fragment or activity.

i want to set pager tab in the fragment from the activity page.

My code at fragment page (FragmentDesign)

```
public void setTabto(int position) {
        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
```

From main activity i tries with this code

```
fragmentDesign = new FragmentDesign();
fragmentDesign.setTabto(2);
```

While running this code i am getting this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.apps.tamilnews, PID: 5302
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.apps.tamilnews.Fragments.FragmentDesign.setTabto(FragmentDesign.java:63)
```

Comment: check your PagerAdapter how many count did you put into public int getCount() method

Comment: This my fragmentdesign fragment page http://pastebin.com/3zaRsG5e